# How should i handle a dependency in my static library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries

I have written a static library which interfaces with a web service for internal use across multiple projects.

This library uses `AFNetworking` heavily, but so do the projects which will use the library. If I include `AFNetworking` in the library.

I get duplicate symbol errors, but if I remove `AFNetworking` from the library, it won't compile.

How should I address this dependency ?

Edit: My project is in a GIT repository. Whatever I do, other developers should be able to pull the project and have it compile successfully (unless I am wrong and I shouldn't be that way).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to rename AFNetworking Classes.

Go to each `.m` file of afnetwork, click on class name, then Edit->Refactor->Rename
.There are around 10 files. It wouldn't take you long.

PS: A good practise is to prepend your library initials, for example if your library name is MyLibrary, you can rename AFNetworking classes like
MyLibAFNetworking... MyLibAFHTTP....

Comment: That sounds very hacky, but it might actually be the right solution. It's the only one that makes the library truly self-sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cocoapods, you can add the dependency for AFNetworking and it will automatically add the library and everything will work like a charm.  https://cocoapods.org/

Comment: I was looking at cocoapods, but my projects do not have workspaces. I was trying to avoid using them so that individual projects could be downloaded from my repository and worked on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files of AFNetworking project and add them to your project as files of your library. In other words,

- Right click on any AFNetworking file in your project and do Show in Finder.
- Select all the AFNetworking files.
- Drag them to your Library project and then drop them.
- When the pop up appears make sure Copy Items if needed is check marked.

Cheers!